# unable to set opacity for a gdkwindow on microsoft windows

Tags: gtk

Itry to make a gtkwindow transparent on microsoft windows but nothing seems to works, It is possible to make a toplevel gtkwindow tranparent on microsoft windows?? some code will be a good thing.
I'm on windows 7 which have a transparency functionality available
Thank

Comment: A piece of code would help

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about gtk2 on windows, it does not support transparency at all.

In your code where you try to get the rgba visual required for alpha channel, you will get None.